# cocoa Mixing audio from two microphines

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, audio

I'm trying trying to find solution for mixing audio from two mics.
For now I have 2 video avcapturesession with one audio (input and output) and one video(input and output) for each one.
How I can mix audio two cmsamplebufferref to one and after that send mixed cmsamplebufferref to file writing?
Or maybe I can add two different audio inputs to one avcapturesession and got mixed cmsamplebufferref from one output?
Any ideas?

Thank you for any advice.